# Temporarily disable files in macOs

Tags: macos, shell-script, bash-scripting, automator

Is there a convenient way to temporarily make files 'not found' to the OS (or more specifically, an App)?
I was thinking an automator action that just adds '.DISABLED' to the filenames, but automator doesn't have a way to append an extension, only replace it. But if it's replaced then when I want to do the reverse and re-enabled these files by removing the '.DISABLED', their original extension will be forgotten which is not what I want.

Perhaps a bash script would be appropriate, but I have a hunch it would involve patterns or regex which is beyond my scope.

Is there a workaround for automator's limited processing of file extensions?

I need this to work recursively on subfolders and keep file structure intact.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this question. What are you actually trying to do? Which process should not be able to find the files? Do you want to exclude them from Spotlight? Or hide them from Finder?

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)?

Comment: The files are part of Ableton Live's library and are unneeded bloat and clutter. Renaming them will prevent Ableton from finding them temporarily, and restoring their original filenames will put things back vanilla which is what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### To amend the extension:

[image]

#### To restore the extension:

[image]

Comment: @Kez, did this work or are you still having problems ?

Comment: This is exactly what tried first, but for some reason it was replacing the extension for me (Name.DISABLED). Must have done something wacky.

Comment: But this time round it's working, I presume ?  If so, I'm glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Not for the faint of heart:

You can put those files into the **trash bin**... there even is a feature which will restore the files back to their previous location. (Of course please don't *ever* do that with critical system files.)

Comment: Ofcourse that would work but there are many files in many folders so far too tedious. This is the perfect thing to tackle with Automator or a script, but Automator's file rename prevents adding another extension.

Comment: The feature to restore files back can't be performed programmatically, I don't believe, which would mean leaving it to the user to open up the trash and restore them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Not the fastest, but reliable & safe.

Compress them & discard the originals.
Select your files, right click, "Compress *n* Items"

Comment: As stated the files exist in a structure and need to remain there for restoration if needed later.

Comment: ...which would be the case using this method. Why would it break hierarchy? Unless you need to be more selective than whole folders, in which case you should add that information to your question.

Comment: Ok yes I probably should have been clearer. The folder structure needs to stay, but the files need to go. If I zip and delete, folder go too.